# Copying ModelMetaData to Child Property's ModelMetaData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, .net-4.0, view

I've created a wrapper model which contains an inner property, Value, which is the property to be shown in the view. In the outermost model, I create a property which is the type of the wrapper and I apply some attributes and validations to that property. When the wrapper view is rendering, I want to copy all validations and attributes from the wrapper to the inner Value property so that when I finally call `EditorFor(m => m.Value)`, the view that renders the child property also renders the validators, etc. related to the container property.

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new IndexModel());
        }
    }
}
```

**IndexModel.cs**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models.Home
{
    public class IndexModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Test Edit Field")]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        [AdditionalMetadata("ViewName", "String")]
        [TemplateVisibility(false, true)]
        public BatchEditField<string> TestEditField { get; set; }

        public IndexModel()
        {
            this.TestEditField = new BatchEditField<string>("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

**EditField.cs** (The "wrapper" model.)

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models.Home
{
    public class EditField
    {
        public string RawValue { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public EditField() { }

        public EditField(string rawValue, object value, string description = null)
        {
            this.RawValue = rawValue;
            this.Value = value;
            this.Description = (description ?? Convert.ToString(value));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Description;
        }
    }

    public class EditField<T> : BatchEditField
    {
        public new T Value { get { return (T)base.Value; } set { base.Value = value; } }

        public EditField() { }

        public EditField(string defaultValue) : base(null, defaultValue, null) { }

        public EditField(string rawValue, T value, string description = null)
            : base(rawValue, value, description)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**EditField.cshtml** (The "wrapper" view.)

```
@using S3.Common.Extensions
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Home.EditField

@{
    //Attempting to copy AdditionalValues from the wrapper property to the child Value property.
    ModelMetadata property = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Single(o => "Value".Equals(o.PropertyName));

    foreach (var item in this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues)
    {
        property.AdditionalValues[item.Key] = item.Value;
    }
}

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value, Convert.ToString(this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ValueOrDefault("ViewName")))

@if (this.Model != null && !this.Model.RawValue.IsNullOrEmpty() && !this.Model.RawValue.Trim().IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    <p class="RawValue@(this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Style") ? " " + this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Style"] : "")">@(this.Model.RawValue.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "(Not Specified)" : this.Model.RawValue)</p>
}
```

**String.cshtml** (The child view.)

```
@* Inspecting this.ViewData.ModelMetaData.AdditionalValues shows that it is empty; the parent AdditionalValues that were copied in the wrapper view did not make it through. *@
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
@Html.ValidationMessage(string.Empty)
```

**Summary**

Finally, when the page is rendered, no validation elements, etc. are included because they don't exist in the ModelMetaData when String.cshtml is rendered.